# Calculating a measure in different ways

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot-table, dax

Suppose I have two products (A,B) under two different categories (C,D) respectively. And let's assume there are already two measures defined.

In DAX, I want to define a third measure, that is the sum of the two measures if the category is C, and the product if the category is D.

I want to create only one measure.

I searched a lot but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

New Measure = IF([Category] = "C", [Measure1] + [Measure2], [Measure1] * [Measure2])

Comment: I already tried this but did not work. I got an error about "Category" to be a multi value column and this logical expression is not allowed.

Comment: It would have been useful to put that fact in your post. You should post your data model as part of the question.